# Dynamically adding elements to ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I will try to explain my problem with adding elements to my `ArrayAdapter` and refresh the `ListView`:

I have two tabs [TAB1][TAB2], with two `Fragments` and attached with `TabListeners`.

1. I request a `WebService` to retrieve my first elements (15 items more or less) of the `ListView`, with `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0x01, null, this);`
2. If I scroll at the bottom of the `ListView`, I request to populate more items (20 items more or less), with `AsyncTask`.
3. `AsyncTask` add more items to an `ArrayAdapter`, then I `mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
4. Click on the [TAB2] and then return to [TAB1]
5. The `initLoader` is called again, BUT the `ArrayAdapter` still have the elements of the first call!

I'm missing something? I need to store the `ArrayAdapter`, `onSaveInstance` or similar?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

when you create ArrayAdapter you send a ListArray to it.when you want change content .you only change this listArray then where you do't want Listview show your  already items you should empty this listArray.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I solved the question, as you say, changing this ListArray.

Comment: I'm newbe and I can't vote up your answer, I only have 6 point of reputation, and the minimum is 15.